# Can't install mpv on Ubuntu 20.04.3 due to dependent packages are "not installable"

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I'm trying to install mpv player on fresh Ubuntu 20.04.3 installation with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
sudo apt update && sudo apt install mpv
```

But response is as follows:

```
$ sudo apt install mpv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mpv : Depends: libaom0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libbluray2 (>= 1:0.2.2) but it is not installable
       Depends: libbs2b0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libdvdnav4 (>= 4.1.3) but it is not installable
       Depends: libfdk-aac1 (>= 0.1.4) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgme0 (>= 0.5.5) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgsm1 (>= 1.0.18) but it is not installable
       Depends: libmodplug1 (>= 1:0.8.8.5) but it is not installable
       Depends: libmysofa1 (>= 0.7~) but it is not installable
       Depends: librubberband2 (>= 1.8.2) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-drm2 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-wayland2 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-x11-2 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva2 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libx265-179 (>= 3.2) but it is not installable
       Depends: libxvidcore4 (>= 1.2.2) but it is not installable
       Recommends: i965-va-driver but it is not installable or
                   libva-intel-vaapi-driver but it is not installable or
                   va-driver but it is not installable
       Recommends: mesa-vdpau-drivers but it is not going to be installed or
                   nvidia-vdpau-driver but it is not installable or
                   nvidia-driver-binary or
                   nvidia-current but it is not installable or
                   vdpau-driver
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is the possible source of problem could be here? I tried to fix broken dependencies with `sudo apt-get -f install`, but result is the same.
Trying to install each package manually doesn't help as well:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libaom0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libaom0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libaom0' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: fyi:  A quick cli query &  I get `libaom0 | 1.0.0.errata1-3build1 | focal/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` showing it's available for your release and found in 'universe' which is enabled by default for *flavors* but not main Ubuntu ('universe' doesn't come with 5 years of support; thus it requires you to okay it's use). You could also use https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to search

Comment: @guiverc you right, that helped, thanks a lot! Still, now I wonder if there is a way to figure out required repository by myself, in case such a scenario occur in future? I'm sorry being still very new in linux environment in general, so I feel missing some fundamental knowledge.

Comment: the command I used was `rmadison libaom0` (however it needs to be installed & isn't available by default on a new install) and it listed it's availability for all supported releases (including ESM which is more than https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libaom0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all I did provide gives... you'll note the '**universe**' is in bold, so it's not really hidden (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)